# ADFS 2.0 claim rules for consuming SAML CA Site minder assertion

Tags: saml, adfs2.0, claims

I am using ADFS 2.0 as a service provider and CA Site Minder as an IDP which issues SAML attributes in the form of:

```
            <ns1:Attribute AttributeName="EmailAddress" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims">
                <ns1:AttributeValue>xxx@gmail.com</ns1:AttributeValue>
```

does anyone know how to setup a claim rule to consume this attribute In ADFS?

I have tried the following as a custom claim but it didn't work:

c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/EmailAddress"]
 => issue(claim = c);

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup up pass-through rules for ADFS and your RP?

ADFS will only pass-through the claims you tell it to,

The normal claims-rules won't work (i.e. the LDAP ones) because ADFS is not the IDP in this case.'

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I did set up a custom rule as well between Adfs and my RP :

c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/EmailAddress"]
 => issue(Type = "http://xxx/emailaddress", Value = c.Value);

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from claim mapping between ADFS and my RP because in my test environment ( using thinktecture identity server as IDP ) everything was working fine.
I think there is a problem in the incoming claim from my client IDP ( CA siteminder ). Do you agree with my first post? Do you think that's the correct way to set up the claim rule in order to consume the incoming claim?

Comment: I forget to mention that in the < AttributeStatement > there is :
<ns1:AttributeStatement>
 <ns1:Subject>

<ns1:NameIdentifier Format="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN"                    NameQualifier="">xxx</ns1:NameIdentifier>
</ns1:Subject>
<ns1:Attribute AttributeName="EmailAddress" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims">
                <ns1:AttributeValue>xxx@gmail.com</ns1:AttributeValue>
</ns1:Attribute>

</ns1:AttributeStatement>